# Android use case unit test

Tags: android, kotlin, junit, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines

Here is my use case code interface -

```
interface ItemUseCase {

     fun performItemAction(action: ItemAction): LiveData<Result>

}
```

Here is the implementation -

```
class ItemUseCaseImpl(
    private val dataRepository: DataRepository
) : ItemUseCase {

    override fun performItemAction(action: ItemAction) = liveData {
        emit(Result.Loading)
        emit(dataRepository.performDataAction(action))
    }
}
```

I am new in writing unit tests. So I need help with -

1) What all I can test in my use case

2) Also I tried to write some unit test below but how do I put LiveData in `thenReturn`

Here is my unit test code -

```
class ItemUseCaseImplTest {

    @Rule
    @JvmField
    val rule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @Mock
    private lateinit var itemUseCase: ItemUseCase

    @Mock
    private lateinit var dataRepository: DataRepository

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        dataRepository = mockk()
        itemUseCase = ItemUseCaseImpl(dataRepository)
    }

    @After
    fun tearDown() {
    }

    @Test
    fun performItemAction() {
        runBlocking {
            whenever(
                itemUseCase.performItemAction(
                    ItemAction.RegisterUser(“xyz”, "20")
                )
            )
                .thenReturn(???)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are mocking the data response so you need to response the data that you want to test.

Comment: Can you please explain me with a simple example

Comment: You are going to test the `ItemUseCaseImpl` so you need to mock the data response when you invoke the method `performDataAction` in the repository. It will respond to the data. 

You don't need to mock the object under test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the example code.

My repository

```
interface RepositoryInterface {
    suspend fun performAPI(): Result<Map<String, Top100Item>>
}

class Repository(private val service: GameService) : RepositoryInterface {
    override suspend fun performAPI(): Result<Map<String, Top100Item>> = try {
        Result.Success(service.getTop100())
    } catch (exception: Exception) {
        Result.Error(null, exception)
    }
}
```

My `MainViewModel` is extended from ViewModel and implement `GameUserInterface`

```
interface GameUserCase {
    fun getGames(): LiveData<Result<Map<String, Top100Item>>>
}

class MainViewModel(
    private val repository: RepositoryInterface,
    private val dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO,
    private val loadingResource: Result<Map<String, Top100Item>> = Result.Loading(null)
) : ViewModel(), GameUserCase {

    override fun getGames(): LiveData<Result<Map<String, Top100Item>>> = liveData(dispatcher) {
        emit(loadingResource)
        emit(repository.performAPI())
    }
}
```

And here is the test example to test the MainViewModel:

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class MainViewModelTest {

    @Mock
    private lateinit var repository: RepositoryInterface

    private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel

    private val testDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    @get:Rule
    var coroutinesTestRule = CoroutinesTestRule()

    @Rule
    @JvmField
    var rule: TestRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    private val loading: Result.Loading<Map<String, Top100Item>> = Result.Loading(null)

    private val mockItem = Top100Item(appId = 30, name = "name", developer = "developer", publisher = "publisher")

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        viewModel = MainViewModel(repository, testDispatcher, loading)
    }

    @Test
    fun testGetDataSuccess() {
        testDispatcher.pauseDispatcher()
        val map = mapOf("30" to mockItem)
        val successResult = Result.Success(map)
        runBlockingTest {
            `when`(repository.performAPI()).thenReturn(successResult)

            val result = viewModel.getGames()
            testDispatcher.resumeDispatcher()

            // verify loading
            assertThat(result.getOrAwaitValue()).isEqualTo(loading)

            result.observeForTesting {
                testDispatcher.resumeDispatcher()
                assertThat(result.value).isEqualTo(successResult)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the test class, I will verify the response success when calling `getGames` so the data will respond with `Result.Success`. For `getOrAwaitValue` and `observeForTesting` methods, you can check from [architecture-components-samples](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/master/LiveDataSample/app/src/test/java/com/android/example/livedatabuilder/util/LiveDataTestUtil.kt)

CoroutinesTestRule from [here](https://gist.github.com/manuelvicnt/049ce057fa6b5e5c785ec9fff7c22a7c#file-coroutinestestrule-kt)

Comment: Yes thank you for the detailed example but my UseCaseImpl returns a LiveData<Result> to my viewmodel and how do I use this livedata because I see in your example the viewmodel just receives a Result and not LiveData<Result>

Comment: You can return the `livedata` for mock

Comment: Yes but I use a livedata and not mutablelivedata. So I cannot use postValue in order to post a value for the mocked livedata

Comment: Use mutableLiveData

Comment: Yes but I don't want to change my implementation just for unit test ;) is there no other possibility?

Comment: You don't need to change your implementation. The mockdata return mutableLiveData

Comment: Oh can you please show me with an example how. It would be really helpful